# Org-mode: why do headlines with parenthesis in them change color?

Tags: org-mode

Here's an example:

```
* my item (note)
```

The note causes the text in the headline to change color, from the headline's usual color to my default text color. How do I disable this?

Comment: This doesn't happen on my system. Can you try it with `emacs -q` to see if it happens without your configuration files?

Comment: It was caused by rainbow-delimiters mode. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using org-mode with rainbow-delimiters-mode and don't see this.  Maybe because I'm using emacs 25?

Comment: Maybe, I'm on 24.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interaction with rainbow-delimiters mode. Shutting that off fixes the problem.